# Android : Difference between deploy on Device and Emulators

Tags: android, sdk, adb

Can anyone tell me, what the difference between deploy apps on device and emulators?

Because some birdnews says, "you can't trust emulators for developing apps".

And what Advantages and disadvantages between deploying on device and emulators?

thanks!

Comment: If you test your app on real devices, you can see how it reacts on your OS. While emulators are based on simulations and you not always can trust the reactions on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting it as an answer since it is too long for a comment.There are a few differences between testing on a device and testing on emulator. Although emulators replicate real devices very well, however on an emulator, you can test your app only for stock Android and the simulation is not very reliable as stated by @C0dekid. The display of the emulator is limited to type if screen(LCD, LED) it is projected on to, hence if your app has displays for high end device screens, you would see an average display on the emulator. However on a real device, you can know how exactly the app reacts to different android versions and ROMs. You can also test for various hardware related features if app easily in a device easily.